# Reach nested array item using recursion - javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to reach the center of a nested array using recursion. This is part of a larger problem I'm trying to solve. I'm sure the solution is somewhat elementary. I've been learning JS/web dev and am stumped.

Here's my code:

```
var j = [[[["hey!"]]]];

function getNested(obj) {
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
        obj = obj[i];
        getNested(obj);
    } 
    return obj[i];
  } 
}
```

The function is supposed to return the 'hey!' string, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Why is there a `for` loop if you'll only ever find the first innermost nested element and return it? How is your code recursive?

Comment: What if there is more than one element in any of the nested arrays?

Comment: I don't see a place where `getNested` calls itself, be it directly or through mutual recursion.

Comment: What is `findType`? If you're looking for recursion, switch out that line for `return getNested(obj)`

Comment: Don't u mean `getNested(obj)` ?

Comment: Here is a solution but its not very applicable outside of this context: http://jsfiddle.net/MfQgR/  If your going to have one element inside a bunch of nested arrays your better off just having a var.

Comment: I can't see recursion in your code. getNested() should call itself somewhere. What if your array looks like that ["hey1",[[["hey!", "hey2"]]]] for example? What should be returned?

Comment: Sorry...changed the name of the function before posting and forgot to change the other instance to getNested(). Posted edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, just switch out the `findType(obj)` for `return getNested(obj[i])`. This will give you a recursive function that drills down into the array until the item in the array is *not* another array. Also, the for-loop was unnecessary, given your example input.

This will ***only*** work if your nested arrays have exactly ***one*** element. Others have expressed this in the comments.

```
var j = [[[["hey!"]]]];

function getNested(obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return getNested(obj[0]);
    } 
    return obj;
}

var str = getNested(j);
console.log(str); // "hey!"
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PkAWt/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for recursion, a simple while loop will already do the trick

```
var j = [[[["hey!"]]]];

function getNested(obj) {
    while (Array.isArray(obj)) { obj = obj[0]; } 
    return obj;
}

var str = getNested(j);
console.log(str); // "hey!"
```

The recursive implementation has the nice property that it is purely functional though if you rewrite it like so:

```
var j = [[[["hey!"]]]];

function getNested(obj) {
    return Array.isArray(obj)? getNested(obj[0]): obj;
}

var str = getNested(j);
console.log(str); // "hey!"
```

Still its performance would be worse though.

Comment: It uses a loop instead of recursion. Thus it should perform significantly better for deeply nested arrays.

Comment: May be you shoud write *There is NO need for recursion*

Comment: The recursive solution has the only advantage that it could be written in a more compressed way like so:  function getNested(obj) { return Array.isArray(obj)? getNested(obj[0]): obj; }  Still its performance would be worse.